# Trying to write a loop with a group_by in it, R

Tags: r, loops, group

I am trying to write a loop that is grouped by ID and replaces values within each group. There are 4 time points. And for a range of variables I want to have the first time point replace the other 3 time points. However, outside of the group of variables I am concerned with, I would like the data to remain the same.

Here is some sample data:

```
structure(list(unqid = c(248, 248, 248, 248, 260, 260, 260, 260, 
3245, 3245, 3245, 3245, 3356, 3356, 3356, 3356, 5777, 5777, 5777, 
5777, 6670, 6670, 6670, 6670), time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), risk_period = c("baseline", 
"0 to 2", "2 to 6", "6 to 12", "baseline", "0 to 2", "2 to 6", 
"6 to 12", "baseline", "0 to 2", "2 to 6", "6 to 12", "baseline", 
"0 to 2", "2 to 6", "6 to 12", "baseline", "0 to 2", "2 to 6", 
"6 to 12", "baseline", "0 to 2", "2 to 6", "6 to 12"), log_Cer.d18.0.24.1. = 
c(1.75591357030424, 
1.78808074202933, 1.78808074202933, 2.12541503739623, 1.82304843124874, 
1.84784683417316, 1.84784683417316, 1.660523253172, 1.71686160700412, 
1.53021484400339, 1.53021484400339, NA, 1.89959518683134, 2.13535376890766, 
2.13535376890766, 1.85969746880244, 1.79719659193748, NA, NA, 
1.58721201454406, 1.58269404870719, NA, NA, NA), log_Cer.d18.1.20.0. = 
c(2.0779936380825, 
1.91571413701583, 1.91571413701583, 2.37155913815626, 1.90173659734545, 
2.17760248999473, 2.17760248999473, 2.25151395301426, 1.92254402612409, 
2.13414350086059, 2.13414350086059, NA, 2.06112457583167, 2.11854093530707, 
2.11854093530707, 2.16685493654321, 1.78492915001842, NA, NA, 
1.88865763010095, 1.90477840908931, NA, NA, NA), log_GlcCer..d18.1.18.0. = 
c(1.37530467341568, 
1.26149055730786, 1.26149055730786, 2.20534847316661, 1.37179016097532, 
1.94465372915655, 1.94465372915655, 1.86255558272858, 1.39432569370228, 
1.80008523512444, 1.80008523512444, NA, 1.59814912304543, 1.65836069384085, 
1.65836069384085, 1.80053131813665, 1.30323667707535, NA, NA, 
1.66851539788016, 1.79824483492343, NA, NA, NA), log_GlcCer..d18.1.20.0. = 
c(1.68455467959852, 
1.68084892938971, 1.68084892938971, 2.83694873855279, 1.98660174822612, 
2.11687085647631, 2.11687085647631, 1.94521751150187, 1.94408113760572, 
2.3144321228024, 2.3144321228024, NA, 1.86220914942921, 2.08792541332488, 
2.08792541332488, 2.14127700040429, 1.25556058999258, NA, NA, 
1.75839585512294, 1.85392719235767, NA, NA, NA), log_SM.d18.0.22.0. = 
c(3.16608443039769, 
2.81581789967824, 2.81581789967824, 3.57758543823053, 3.05566675337641, 
2.71402626524511, 2.71402626524511, 2.74435051671931, 3.18268277797341, 
3.06067406280674, 3.06067406280674, NA, 3.00579040289776, 3.43150364762063, 
3.43150364762063, 2.92413057011273, 2.89178396996734, NA, NA, 
2.65395668019336, 2.61724748884637, NA, NA, NA), log_SM.d18.1.18.0. = 
c(4.12097226184649, 
3.97496147376645, 3.97496147376645, 4.39933846293122, 3.95478500357647, 
4.04453196517474, 4.04453196517474, 4.14121011613781, 3.89734856154778, 
4.00561959288859, 4.00561959288859, NA, 4.01511036918758, 4.00986157943819, 
4.00986157943819, 3.97023826969138, 3.86134148535091, NA, NA, 
3.77303147344872, 4.06523949171878, NA, NA, NA), log_SM.d18.1.24.1. = 
c(4.80118834282449, 
4.58079754854406, 4.58079754854406, 5.29872341013633, 4.89353600842266, 
5.01659126290913, 5.01659126290913, 5.01117232938486, 4.87122149340715, 
4.81332745585807, 4.81332745585807, NA, 4.88235204875765, 4.92826803352429, 
4.92826803352429, 4.78283431218245, 4.3613226254187, NA, NA, 
4.58555011488179, 4.63520556565684, NA, NA, NA), cancer = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(917L, 918L, 919L, 920L, 3458L, 3459L, 3460L, 
3461L, 4286L, 4287L, 4288L, 4289L, 4290L, 4291L, 4292L, 4293L, 
4462L, 4463L, 4464L, 4465L, 4506L, 4507L, 4508L, 4509L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the syntax I use to group the column names of concern together:

```
## Find first ceramide column
cer.start <- which(colnames(long_data) == "log_Cer.d18.0.24.1."); cer.start #Note 
in R, two "==" signs are used to denote equals to
## Find last ceramide column
cer.stop <- which(colnames(long_data) == "log_SM.d18.1.24.1."); cer.stop
#select all ceramide column names between the first and last ceramide
ceramides <- colnames(long_data)[cer.start:cer.stop]
```

There are 4 different time points. For the variables created in the ceramide object, I would like time 1 data to replace the data for times 2,3, and 4. So they will just have repeating data for all time points. I want to group by ID. So that the repeating data is only within person. Additionally, for the variables not in the ceramide object, their data should remain unchanged.

I have tried a couple different things:

```
long_data_cancer_ceramide_test<-
for (i in colnames(ceramides)) {
long_data_cancer_ceramide %>% 
group_by(unqid) %>% 
mutate("i" = i [time==1])
}

long_data_cancer_ceramide_test<-long_data_cancer_ceramide%>%
group_by(unqid)%>%
lapply(ceramides, function(x) mutate(x = x [time==1]))
```

However, these attempts did not work. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: `i` is a column name, not the column vector, you cannot subset `i [time==1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

long_data = long_data %>%
  group_by(unqid) |>
  mutate(across(log_Cer.d18.0.24.1. : log_SM.d18.1.24.1., first)) |>
  ungroup()

long_data
# # A tibble: 24 × 11
#    unqid  time risk_period log_Cer.d18.0.24.1. log_Cer.d18.1.20.0. log_GlcCer..d18.1.18.0. log_GlcC…¹ log_S…² log_S…³ log_S…⁴ cancer
#    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl>               <dbl>                   <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1   248     1 baseline                   1.76                2.08                    1.38       1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
#  2   248     2 0 to 2                     1.76                2.08                    1.38       1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
#  3   248     3 2 to 6                     1.76                2.08                    1.38       1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
#  4   248     4 6 to 12                    1.76                2.08                    1.38       1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
#  5   260     1 baseline                   1.82                1.90                    1.37       1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
#  6   260     2 0 to 2                     1.82                1.90                    1.37       1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
#  7   260     3 2 to 6                     1.82                1.90                    1.37       1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
#  8   260     4 6 to 12                    1.82                1.90                    1.37       1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
#  9  3245     1 baseline                   1.72                1.92                    1.39       1.94    3.18    3.90    4.87      0
# 10  3245     2 0 to 2                     1.72                1.92                    1.39       1.94    3.18    3.90    4.87      0
# # … with 14 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​log_GlcCer..d18.1.20.0., ²​log_SM.d18.0.22.0., ³​log_SM.d18.1.18.0.,
# #   ⁴​log_SM.d18.1.24.1.
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uncount()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

long_data |> 
  group_by(unqid) |> 
  filter(time == 1) |> 
  uncount(4) |>
  ungroup()
```

Alternate version using row weights instead of `filter`:

```
long_data |> 
  group_by(unqid) |> 
  uncount(c(4, 0, 0, 0))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 24 × 11
   unqid  time risk_period log_Cer.d18.0.24.1. log_Cer.d18.…¹ log_G…² log_G…³ log_S…⁴ log_S…⁵ log_S…⁶ cancer
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   248     1 baseline                   1.76           2.08    1.38    1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
 2   248     1 baseline                   1.76           2.08    1.38    1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
 3   248     1 baseline                   1.76           2.08    1.38    1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
 4   248     1 baseline                   1.76           2.08    1.38    1.68    3.17    4.12    4.80      0
 5   260     1 baseline                   1.82           1.90    1.37    1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
 6   260     1 baseline                   1.82           1.90    1.37    1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
 7   260     1 baseline                   1.82           1.90    1.37    1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
 8   260     1 baseline                   1.82           1.90    1.37    1.99    3.06    3.95    4.89      0
 9  3245     1 baseline                   1.72           1.92    1.39    1.94    3.18    3.90    4.87      0
10  3245     1 baseline                   1.72           1.92    1.39    1.94    3.18    3.90    4.87      0
# … with 14 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​log_Cer.d18.1.20.0., ²​log_GlcCer..d18.1.18.0.,
#   ³​log_GlcCer..d18.1.20.0., ⁴​log_SM.d18.0.22.0., ⁵​log_SM.d18.1.18.0., ⁶​log_SM.d18.1.24.1.
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```